How can I block TikTok mobile app using Huawei HG8245H5 GPON router?
I tried to block TikTok by URL on the Huawei HG8245H5 GPON router, but it only blocks on the computer, not on the mobile app.
How can I block the TikTok mobile app using the Huawei HG8245H5 GPON router?

Hi, looks like your question was migrated to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange, a Q&A site for Android end-users. However, based on the writing, looks like you're trying to block it using the router. Just to confirm, are you open to solutions outside of the router, i.e. directly from Android?
